# How to set the number of vertices by shape digitizing tool in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis-3, circle, ellipse

Can we set the number of vertices of the created circle or ellipse.
(e.g. a circle/ellipse with 24 or 36 vertices)
I can use "add regular polygon and set the point #" for circle, but i don't know how to set the ellipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#add-circular-string), shapes digitized with these tools use curved geometries:

> Curved geometries are stored as such only in compatible data provider
>
> Although QGIS allows to digitize curved geometries within any editable
> data format, you need to be using a data provider (e.g. PostGIS,
> memory layer, GML or WFS) that supports curves to have features stored
> as curved, otherwise QGIS segmentizes the circular arcs.

So there is no option to control the number of vertices. So e.g. a circle as temporary layer will only have five *(four + one "closing"-vertex)* vertices. If you save it as shapefile, this curved geometry will be splitted into small straight line segements. An option would be to use **"Simplify"** algorithm from processing toolbox.

To illustrate: Here a circle digitized as temporary layer and then saved as shapefile. The points represent the extracted vertices of the polygons:

[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you! Because I only edit local data source of Shape file format, which doesn't support the arc or curved geometry. There are a lot of vertices of a new circle/curved line/ellipse feature created by the digitizing tool for shape file data source, as shown in your illustration. 
I think that I can use the "simplify feature" action or "simplify..." tool for reducing the number of vertices if I need more simple geometry.